Create Remediation Task is Greyed Out on Managed Identity ACA built-in policy

Unable to Create Remediation Task on managed identity ACA built in policy.
Although compliance state is working fine on all resources.
Need to remediate non compliant resources. The question is, do Remediation applicable on managed identity built-in policy?
See image above thank you!

Do you want to enable identity for all non-resource container apps.

The main goal is to enable identity for all non-compliant using remediation. Thank you  @VenkatV!

Are you looking only for an Azure Policy approach, or is it also acceptable to use PowerShell or CLI to enable identity for container apps?

If remediation is not applicable then any policy that automates the Enable Identity for non-compliant container apps.

Yes, you can use one policy to check non-complaint resource and PowerShell script to enable Identity for container apps.

Is this the same scenario for remediation? Can you provide a sample script or how to trigger that policy as well? thank you @VenkatV

The default policy does not support enabling identity; instead, you must create a custom policy to enable identity.Instead of policy, using a powershell script in an automation account is a simple way to automatically enable identity without manual intervention.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

To enable System Managed Identity, since there is no built-in policy for this, you need to create a custom policy
Alternatively, you can also achieve the same requirement of enabling system-managed identity in container apps using PowerShell with an automation account. This way, it will automatically enable the identity for the container if it's not already enabled.
1.Go to portal >  automation account >  Create an Automation Account

Create a runbook with type powershell



Open  Runbook > Edit in Portal > add below script and click on Publish


Note: The automation Identity must have the Contributor role assigned to enable the System Managed Identity in container apps.

   az login --identity
  $containerApps = az containerapp list --query "[].{Name:name, ResourceGroup:resourceGroup, Identity:identity}" | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    foreach ($app in $containerApps) {
        $appName = $app.Name
        $resourceGroup = $app.ResourceGroup
        $identity = $app.Identity
    
        Write-Output "Processing container app: $appName in resource group: $resourceGroup"
    
        # Check if the app has a system-assigned identity
        if (-not $identity -or $identity.type -eq "None") {
            Write-Output "System-assigned identity is not enabled for $appName. Enabling identity now..."
            az containerapp identity assign --name $appName --resource-group $resourceGroup --system-assigned
            Write-Output "System-assigned identity enabled successfully for $appName."
        } else {
            Write-Output "System-assigned identity is already enabled for $appName."
        }
    }

Output:

You can schedule the runbook to execute a script every day at 5 PM, so it will check all container apps and automatically enable the identity if it's not enabled.

Schedules the runbook > add a schedule > link schedule to yrunbookbook > Create.


Output
After running the runbook, The Identity has been enabled in all container apps.

Reference: Stack link

Hi Venkat, thank you for the above solution, however when i tried to create and insert the script using portal and run the job, error message appeared "ERROR: No access was configured for the VM, hence no subscriptions were found. If this is expected, use '--allow-no-subscriptions' to have tenant level access"
Any advise on how this works?

Can you confirm where you are running the script?

I used Powershell and run into Azure Portal.

Are you running the script in Azure Cloud Shell from the portal? If yes, kindly share the error screenshot.

Hi Venkat, after having the correct way of using the script in portal, i have successfully executed it, thank you once again.
